# Use ThreeBond 1207B when replacing rocker cover gaskets?

Tags: engine, subaru, repair, gasket

I'm planning to replace my rocker cover gaskets and spark plug seals on my 2007 Subaru Outback, as there is a slight oil leak onto the spark plugs.

I've also purchased some ThreeBond 1207B gasket sealer to help with the task.

However the product didn't come with any instructions on how to use it so I'm a bit unsure.

What is the best way to use ThreeBond 1207B when replacing rocker cover gaskets and spark plug seals?

Comment: Check threebond 1207B on the manufacturer’s website.

Comment: I checked website, no info on application....http://www.threebond.com.au/liquid-gaskets.html

Comment: Most rocker cover gaskets are rubber and require so sealants.

Comment: @Moab that seems to be the Australian distributor...

Comment: They are the manufacturer.

Comment: Well, the UK or Europe distributor gave good info...

Comment: @Moab, yeah, actually it seems like you should not use silicone sealants when using rubber gaskets, as it simply will not bond. So I will not use the ThreeBond.

Comment: Only if there are sharp 90 degree corners that may not seal.

Comment: Iirc on late model subarus you need to use silicon when doing the rocker cover gaskets. I forget when this changed or it might be dual cam with cop only. Check SI. All i remember is it’s a pita to clean off the old silicon.

Comment: @Ben I think the rubber sealant is only to be used on the dual cam engines, which may or may not use a different kind of gasket. I checked the 07 service manual and the 6 cylinder engines with dual cam need the sealant, but the 4 cylinder single cam ones (like mine) do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [link](https://www.techsil.co.uk/media/pdf/TDS/TBSI19050-tds.pdf) to the instructions and an image of the most relevant part:

[image]

Comment: Good point and well spotted - saves having to do the job twice...